# MySQL calendar automation with events

Tags: mysql, math, calendar, timestamp

I have never really had the need for using MySQL events, but I am now working on a simple calendar/scheduler table for my application where setting up some automation seems like a good idea. I can easily add new rows to the table like this where timestamp + some increment is the primary key:

```
INSERT INTO events (dates) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()+600)
```

But I am having some difficulty copying old entries to a records table (my current code looks like this):

```
INSERT INTO copy SELECT * FROM events WHERE dates<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-600)
```

And then deleting the old entries from the calendar table:

```
DELETE FROM events WHERE dates<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-600)
```

I really only ever do basic INSERT or SELECT queries, etc. from my applications, so I'm not very familiar with all of the math stuff or other functions available in SQL.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Never mind. The code was working, but my control panel was not updating as quickly as I would have liked. I'll leave this up though for anyone who wants to know how to do this. Any comments are welcome.

Comment: But why would you want to do this?

Comment: The idea is that the calendar should only date back a certain time, say 90 days, and also date forward to show upcoming events, again say 90 days. I want to remove very old records though so that I do not have a lot of useless info to sift through when performing a search - so the events just help keep the tables only as large as they need to be.

Comment: I suspect that the overhead of storing it all in one (properly indexed) table will be trivial.